# text based installion of solaris 10?

Tags: installation, solaris-10

I know text based installation of solaris 10.
Perhaps there are 6 ways of installing it.

Do you think that it is a proper mode to install solaris 10.

I am asking this because if only one way of instalation is sufficient to learn than I should not be concentrating much on other ways installation.

OR each installation type has its own advantages over the other and I need to learn all of them.

EDIT: If some type of installtion really does mattter and is best, which one would you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "best" method to install Solaris, just different ways addressing different needs.

If what you want is just to install the OS, pick the one you like.

If you want to get some expertise in Solaris installation, experiment with all of them including text, graphic, live upgrade, flash archives, jumpstart ...

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/821-0441/planning-222/index.html

Comment: thanks,"just different ways addressing different needs." ---> this sounds like I really need to experiment on the rest of the methods too.

Comment: @munish - Install it in VirtualBox. It's great for trying things out.